# Given array keys that correspond to another array, how can I merge them?

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array that is supposed to only be keys:

```
$keys = ['mod_4_key'];
```

and the bigger array which contains a lot of information:

```
$big_array = [ 'mod_4_key' => ['old' => '', 'info' => ''], 'mod_5_key' => ..]
```

I would like to, based on what is inside `$keys` generate a new array with the information from `$big_array`, as such, if we are to compute the "non-difference" between the arrays, the output should be:

```
$final_array = [ 'mod_4_key' => ['old' => '', 'info' => '']]
```

I achieved this using a classic `foreach` but I was wondering if there was no in-built way to achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be better off with a simple `foreach()` loop, but there are probably several ways of achieving this.

This uses `array_flip()` on the `$keys`, so that you end up with another associative array, then use `array_intersect_key()` with the big array first.

```
$final_array = array_intersect_key($big_array, array_flip($keys));
```

Comment: I'll remain with the `foreach` version, then. It's more terse and avoids me doing two operations.